# Using set-output as a workflow command fails with exit code 3

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

I do not know whether here is a problem in one of my steps regarding an github-workflow-job.

The step looks like this:

```
- name: check_tf_code
   id: tf_check 
   run: |
     terraform fmt -check
     echo '::set-output name=bash_return_Value::$?'
```

and the error output for this step in the log is:
`Error: Process completed with exit code 3`

What could be the problem here? Is GitHub not able to make a bash evaluation for `$?` to get the
info whether the last (terraform) command was successful or not?

Answer (score 1):

Run steps are run with `set -eo pipefail` (see [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#exit-codes-and-error-action-preference)); this means that if any command has a non-zero exit status, the job aborts, including when the command is part of a pipeline.

In your case, this means that if `terraform fmt -check` has a non-zero exit status, the next line is never run.

Then, your output would be literally `$?` because Bash doesn't expand anything in single quotes. You'd have to use

```sh
echo "::set-output name=bash_return_Value::$?"
```

but you already know that when this line is hit, the value of `$?` is `0`.

If you want to do something in case a command fails, you could do

```sh
if ! terraform fmt -check; then
    # Do something
fi
```

because `if` conditions don't trigger the `set -e` behaviour.